# handling redirects between web api and mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing a custom authentication where my users will access my webapi and it will redirect me to a MVC based login page. Once they login, I will have to redirect back to the web api and from there, response will be rendered.

I am using redirect in my webapi and MVC, but t I would like to know if this is the best way to achieve. Kindly suggest.

I am using MVC 5 and web api 2.

Comment: It sounds like an ok approach. Without seeing the code, I couldn't possibly decide if it's the best way or if there is anything wrong (or right) about it. This question might belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am not aware on how to move this to codereview.stackexchange.com. Anyways, the best approach is what I am expecting out from this post.